# UNION ALL or INTERSECT ALL equivalent in R?

Tags: r

R has the builtin functions *union* and *intersect*, which work on vectors and interpret them as sets. This has the side effect that duplicate entries are removed:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,3,1)
> y <- c(1,1,2)
> union(x,y)
[1] 1 2 3
> intersect(x,y)
[1] 1 2
```

Is there a possibility to get the vectors be treated as *multisets* (aka *bags*), like in SQL the modifier ALL does?

The results should be (1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3) for *union* and (1,1,2) for *intersect*.

**Addendum (clarification):**
An element, which occurs *n* times in *x* and *m* times in *y*, should be

- *n* + *m* times in the union
- min(*n*, *m*) times in the intersection
- max(*n*-*m*, 0) times in the difference (*x* except *y*)

Comment: Is this what you need? `sort(c(x,y))`

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes, UNION ALL is the same as concatenation. Unfortunately, I need intersection. And merge creates a Cartesion product by default. Adding a JOIN condition will not help, because this creates n times m result tuples for elements occurring n times in x and m times in y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vecsets::vintersect()` does exactly what you want for intersection:

> Unlike the base::intersect function, if the vectors have repeated elements in common, the intersection returns as many of these elements as are in whichever vector has fewer of them.

```
vecsets::vintersect(x,y)
# [1] 1 1 2
```

Unfortunately, `vecsets::vunion()` follows a different definition than yours, which seems to be just concatenation, as pointed out by others:

```
c(x,y)
# [1] 1 2 3 3 1 1 1 2
```

Comment: Yes, that is the function that I was looking for. The implementation of *vunion* is strange: it returns each element *mx(n,m)* times. Not the textbook definition of bag union, but it might be useful in some circumstances...
Unfortunately, *install.packages("vecsets")* returns an error about a '<!DOCTYPE html> ...' formatting error. But when I download the tar.gz, I can install it from the command line.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Just tried `install.packages("vecsets")` in R 3.6.3 on Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and it works fine on both for me.

Comment: It seems to depend on the R version: with R 3.5, I can install it with *install.packages*, with R 3.1, I must download the source and install it. The implementation itself works for every R version.

Answer (score 3):

A `base` solution:

```
sort(x[x %in% y])
[1] 1 1 2

sort(c(x,y)) 
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Based on the **edit**:

```
 x <- c(1,2,3,3,1)
  y <- c(1,1,2)
 c(min(x[x %in% y]),unique(y[y%in%x]))
[1] 1 1 2
 x = c(1,1,1)
y = c(1,1,5)
 c(min(x[x %in% y]),unique(y[y%in%x]))
[1] 1 1
```

Comment: Wow, that's clever! I was not aware that %in% is vectorized. Actually, I do not need the sort.

Comment: Oh sorry, just noticed that it does not work: for x = c(1,1,1) and y = c(1,1), the result of the intersection should be (1,1) and not (1,1,1).

Comment: Why should it be 1,1 though? It seems you only want to select y and not x ie y in x not x in y? In that case: `y[y %in% x]`

Comment: I have added an explanation in my question how the set operations are defined for *bags* or *multisets*.

Comment: I have added a variant.I may not be online since it's late where I am. You can leave a comment here if it doesn't work for you and I will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: The *min* only works when the multiple entry is the lowest and only when it should occur twice. Beelow, there is an answer referring to the vecsets package. As it is written in pure R, I could have a look at the implementation of *vintersect*: it first does an ordinary *intersect* and then adds multiple elements afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

For your union example, `sort(union_all(x, y))` gives the desired result.

Not sure about your intersect case, I've never encountered that problem.

Comment: It's in `dplyr.`

Comment: Just checked the dplyr documentation, and the functions *intersect*, *setdiff* and *setequal* that it provedes are merely the base variants overloaded to work with more data types. They do not offer a named argument (e.g. *multiple*, as the versions in vecsets) for dealing correctly with multiple instances of elements.